# Ability to track separate user sessions on a website

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to figure out a way that I can view pages visited per visitor session on my website through Google Analytics. I essentially want to be able to look at each session and see exactly which pages were visited. I have been researching this but I am still unclear if I can actually track this information. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. The report is **[Audience -> User Explorer](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6339208?hl=en)**.

The User Explorer report lets you isolate and examine individual rather than aggregate user behavior. Individual user behavior is associated with either Client-ID or User-ID. If you don't send User-ID, Google Analytics will use Client-ID

Client-ID is assigned by Google Analytics to every user with the first visit to your page, and is available as cookie "_ga" [until the [cookie lifetime](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cookies-user-id), or until user clears cookies].

[User-ID](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123666?hl=en) is, on the other hand, value you can assign [i.e. customer ID in your CMS].

Keep in mind that you must enable [User-ID feature](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6339208?hl=en) and send data to have User explorer reports with that data.

The User ID also lets you associate engagement data from multiple devices and different sessions with unique IDs.

Each unique User ID is considered to be a unique user in Analytics, so you get a more accurate user count in your reports. When you send Analytics an ID and related data over the course of multiple sessions, you can also put individual user actions in context and start analyzing ongoing relationships.